# MySQL Rename table while keeping view for legacy code

Tags: mysql, view

I am renaming multiple tables in a large application. I need to preserve the old table name because some parts of the application will take longer to be updated, we can have no downtime.

My idea is to create a view that selects all from the new table, like this:

```
create view old_table_name as select a as x, b as y, c as z from new_table_name;
```

According to this article (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/view-updatability.html) I will be able to make inserts and updates and deletes with this view.

My question is (considering that this is only a temporary solution in the mean time until we are able to migrate all legacy code to use this new table) will I be able to pull this off?
Will I have a decent enough performance in joins and things alike?
Will I be able to make complex updates or deletes (involving joins) with this approach?

Is there a better way to approach this problem?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The performance should be essentially identical.

For simple views without aggregate functions/group by/having, distinct, limit, unions, scalar subqueries, and views that return literals only, MySQL uses the `MERGE` algorithm by default, which effectively rewites a query referencing such a view as if you had used the columns in the base tables directly.

See [View Algorithms](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/view-algorithms.html) in the documentation.

[Determining what algorithm MySQL view is using](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/54491/11651) may be informative as well.